# Как оптимизировать useSelector redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, оптимизация, redux

Я использую redux useSelector в своем App компоненте с роутами

```
const { something, something2 } = useSelector((state) => ({
      something: state.something,
      something2: state.something2
}))
```

Так же у меня в приложении много логики с dispatch при обновлении страницы.

**ПРОБЛЕМА** в том что мой App компонент обновляется по 10 раз. Как я могу оптимизировать и исправить это?

Мне действительно нужны эти данные из state redux в App компоненте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using memoizing selectors](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors)

Примерно так (синтаксис не проверял):

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

// вне рендера
const selectSomething = createSelector(
    state => state.something,
    state => state.something2,
    (something, something2) => ({ something, something2 })
);

// в рендере
const { something, something2 } = useSelector(selectSomething);
```

Мемойзит селектор по значениям `state.something` и `state.something2`, и возвращает старое значение, если входные значения не поменялись.